# How to use a play/pause button for multiple html5 videos in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a website that has a series of twelve HTML5 videos that starts playing automatically in a separate modal box for each video. Now I want to give the user the control to play and pause the video as well (along with other features but that's not relevant to my current problem).

I've gotten so far that the user are able to click the video itself in order to play and pause it. But the play/pause button i've added does not work right now and the code below will give me a "lastClicked.pause is not a function" error.

I know that the reason is because the lastClicked variable i'm using as a condition inside the if statement will contain a button when I click "play/pause" and a button does not have those functions. I've figured out that much so far, but I'm a bit lost of what my next step should be.

Should I make a reference to the specific video inside the toggleVideo function and replace it with the lastClicked variable or does a more simple solution exist?

EDIT: Added a bit of the HTML for reference

Javascript:

```
// VIDEO CONTROLS
const portfolio = document.querySelector(".portfolio");
const player = portfolio.querySelectorAll(".viewer");
const toggle = portfolio.querySelectorAll(".toggle");

let lastClicked

function toggleVideo () {

    lastClicked = this;

    if(lastClicked.paused) {
        lastClicked.play();    
    }

    else {
        lastClicked.pause();
    }

  }

// Two different ways to play/pause the video - Clicking the video 
// itself and clicking the play/pause button

player.forEach(video => video.addEventListener ("click", toggleVideo ));
toggle.forEach(button => button.addEventListener ("click", toggleVideo ));
```

HTML:

```
<section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">


      <div class="video-wrapper">
          <div class="video-thumbnail"><img src="./media/img/thumbnails/1.hammerfall.jpg"></div>
          <button class="video-overlay" id="player" data-modal="videoOne"></button>
      </div
      ><div class="modal-box">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close-btn">&times;</span>
          <div class="player">
            <video class="player__video viewer" src="./media/video/1.waves.mp4"></video>

            <div class="video-controller">
              <div class="progress-bar">
                <div class="progress-filled"></div>
              </div>
                <button class="video-play toggle">►</button>
                <input type="range" name="volume" class="player-slider" min=0 max=1 step="0,05" value="1">
                <button class="video-volume mute">X</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div

      ><div class="video-wrapper">
          <div class="video-thumbnail"><img src="./media/img/thumbnails/2.lordi.jpg"></div>
          <button class="video-overlay" data-modal="videoTwo"></button>
      </div
      ><div class="modal-box">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close-btn">&times;</span>
            <div class="player">
          <video class="player__video viewer" src="./media/video/2.words.mp4"></video>

            <div class="video-controller">
              <div class="progress-bar">
                <div class="progress-filled"></div>
              </div>
                <button class="video-play toggle">►</button>
                <input type="range" name="volume" class="player-slider" min=0 max=1 step="0,05" value="1">
                <button class="video-volume mute">X</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div
      >
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Essentially you need to associate your buttons with your videos.

Currently `toggleVideo()` assumes that it's running in the context of a `video` element, whereas it could be a video *or* a button *associated* with a video.

You don't know show your HTML structure, but for this answer I'll use the following video-button relationship.

```
<div>
    <video />
    <button>Toggle</button>
</div>
```

...ergo in my contrived example, the button is the next sibling of the video. It doesn't matter what the precise relationship is between `video` and `button`, merely that we establish and cater for it inside `toggleVideo()`.

So, that now becomes:

```
function toggleVideo () {

    //establish video - might be @this, or might be prev sibling of @this
    let vid = this.tagName == 'VIDEO' ? this : this.previousSibling;

    lastClicked = vid;
    vid.paused ? vid.play() : vid.pause();

}
```

Comment: This code in particular did not work BUT it did lead my to my solution.
Instead of this.previousSibling I used this.parentNode.previousElementSibling to target the video in the code i've posted above. Now I can both click the modal and click the play/pause button to make the video start and stop.

Thank you very much!